# Visual Studio Cordova Push Notification Sample Not Working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

Hi I'm trying to use azure mobile service to send APNS push notification to my Cordova app, however I couldn't get it to work by following this article

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879353.aspx

, plus the sample project Microsoft provides is using VS2013 with the deprecated Push Plugin https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

The new push plugin is very differnt from the old one,
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Has anyone get the APNS push notification to work using VS2015 and the new Push plugin and could share a sample code?

Thanks!